# Card drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to move one item to next box, but the event dragover and dragenter wasn't detected. Can someone explain this?

```js
let dropTarget = $('.box'),
  dropSource = $('.inner-box');

dropTarget.on('dropover dropenter', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(1)
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner-box" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: There's no `dropover` or `dropenter` events. I think you mean `dragover` and `dragenter`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Also note that there's a lot of drag & drop libraries available to make your life easier. jQueryUI, for example: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/